# Java splitting strings regex: Leading whitespace

Tags: java, regex, string

I know that the question has been asked before on how to split strings with leading white space, for example:

```
String str = " I want to be  split \t!"
String[] sarr = str.split("\\s+");
for(String s : sarr) System.out.println("'" + s + "'");
```

produces the results:

```
'' //leading white space
'I'
'want'
'to'
'be'
'split'
'!'
```

The way to fix this is to use str.trim() before splitting.

What I'm wondering though is *why* split() cannot skip over leading white space but can do so in the middle/end of the string.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String, int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should answer your question.

Taken from [String docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
>
> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

Comment: My bad, this question probably could have been avoided if I have read the java-doc more carefully than I did. "The array returned by this method contains each substring of this string that is terminated by another substring that matches the given expression or is terminated by the end of the string." Thanks for the prompt reply!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what anirudh said, also note another option: including the leading space with the "I":

```
(?<!^)\s+
```

This gives you

```
 I
want
to
be
split
\t!
```

(and gets rid of the annoying first match)

Answer (score 0):

In Java to match white space on its own native character set, because Java doesn’t support the Unicode white space property — even though doing so is strictly required to meet **[UTS#18’s RL1.2!](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Categories)**

The Unicode Standard for these, so you instead have to use code like this:

```
                     ""       /* dummy empty string for homogeneity */
                     "\\u0009" // CHARACTER TABULATION
                     "\\u000A" // LINE FEED (LF)
                     "\\u000B" // LINE TABULATION
                     "\\u000C" // FORM FEED (FF)
                     "\\u000D" // CARRIAGE RETURN (CR)
                     "\\u0020" // SPACE
                     "\\u0085" // NEXT LINE (NEL) 
                     "\\u00A0" // NO-BREAK SPACE
                     "\\u1680" // OGHAM SPACE MARK
                     "\\u180E" // MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR
                     "\\u2000" // EN QUAD 
                     "\\u2001" // EM QUAD 
                     "\\u2002" // EN SPACE
                     "\\u2003" // EM SPACE
                     "\\u2004" // THREE-PER-EM SPACE
                     "\\u2005" // FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
                     "\\u2006" // SIX-PER-EM SPACE
                     "\\u2007" // FIGURE SPACE
                     "\\u2008" // PUNCTUATION SPACE
                     "\\u2009" // THIN SPACE
                     "\\u200A" // HAIR SPACE
                     "\\u2028" // LINE SEPARATOR
                     "\\u2029" // PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
                     "\\u202F" // NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
                     "\\u205F" // MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
                     "\\u3000" // IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
```